# Unity - How to get location of center of parent gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've a question about how to get the transform created by the addition of child objects to a parent. It's easier to see what I mean by looking at the picture that follows.
[Tranform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7tbl.png)
. I understand that the world position of the parent is effectively at 0 but how do I get the displayed one?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some info, first. That location is where the `Center` of that `GameObject` is. The alternative to having the handles there is at the `Pivot`, which will put the handles at the same location as `Transform.position`. You can toggle between those two handle display modes in the Unity Editor.

So, you want to find the location of the `Center` handles. That depends on if the parent has a `Renderer` or not.

In your situation, where the parent object has no `Renderer`, you have to go into the children of the gameObject and average their transform positions:

```
Vector3 sumVector = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);

foreach (Transform child in parentObject.transform)
{          
    sumVector += child.position;        
}

Vector3 groupCenter = sumVector / parentObject.transform.childCount;
```

If the situation were a little different and the parent gameObject had a `Renderer`, then it is much easier:

```
Vector3 groupCenter = parentObject.getComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;
```

Comment: I'm sure your first answer works for me, I haven't tested it yet. For the second method, I've tried it and it still gives me Vector3(0,0,0)

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. Thanks for the answer of @Ruzihm.
I want to make the center, but don't know whether the object has 'Renderer', so I write recursive function like this to get a center pos of the object.

```
Vector3 getCenter(Transform obj)
{
    Vector3 center = new Vector3();
    if (obj.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
    {
        center = obj.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Transform subObj in obj)
        {
            center += getCenter(subObj);
        }
        center /= obj.childCount;
    }
    return center;
}
```